# Using directBox2D with directCanvas - AppMobi

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, box2d, appmobi

I am busy looking for an easy solution using the Box2D physics engine in directCanvas... without using ImpactJS or any paid for framework.

My end goal is to build a HTML5 game for Mobile (Android/iPhone/iPad etc.) using Box2D.

**What is my best solution?**

Some box2D frameworks I am considering :

- Box2DJS - http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/
- Box2Dflash - http://29a.ch/2010/4/17/box2d-2-flash-ported-javascript
- Gamvas - http://gamvas.com/

---

**-UPDATE-**

AppMobi's **directBox2D** documentation :

http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/gamingAPI/directBox2D/index.html

The only way to use directCanvas and Box2D is by using AppMobi's DirectBox2D framework (This is how I understand it).

**Does anyone have a working example/demo how directBox2D with directCanvas???** I got it working on the XDK emulator but it is not working my Android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think you've found, directBox2D only supports a subset of the Box2D calls. Right now, we are working on enhancing our directCanvas support to reflect more of the HMTL5 spec for both Android and iOS. Expanding directBox2D and that whole API is on our road map. Currently I don't think we've created a demo using directBox2D without ImpactJS and I'll make a note to create one after we enhance the API.

The XDK is made to emulate the phone as best as it can, but if you are using calls that aren't supported in B2D, that won't break until you push to device.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Can't wait for the next release, keep up the great work!